# iOS UIView as dialog box

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is my code. I can see the small dialog box appeared then the dialog take over the whole screen. What is wrong?

```
ChangeProfileImage *changeProfileImage =[[ChangeProfileImage alloc] init];

changeProfileImage.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
changeProfileImage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:changeProfileImage animated:YES];
changeProfileImage.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);//it's important to do this after 
changeProfileImage.view.superview.center = self.view.center
```

Comment: What does ChangeProfileImage inherit from, and what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

I was all ready to tell you everything that's wrong with this code, but then I set up a simple iPad single view application and tried the following code:

```
- (IBAction)FlipPressed:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *view = [vc view];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [[[vc view] superview] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    [[[vc view] superview] setCenter:[[self view] center]];
}
```

When I try this, I get a red box, 200x200, with rounded corners, that flips into view centered on screen.

As far as I can tell, I've replicated your code pretty much exactly, and I think I got the result you want, right?

***EDIT/UPDATE***

Further testing appears to indicate that this code will only work well when the iPad is in the portrait orientation. Otherwise, my view is appear to flip "vertically" (with respect to how the iPad is oriented) and the view isn't centered.

Comment: There still a white background that shows the red box appear but my current view is also removed

Comment: Based on that comment, maybe it's an issue with shocks and struts (UIAutoResizingMask). Can you take a screen shot and post it?